# How can I access values from multidimen array in lua?

Tags: javascript, lua

```
k = {
  messageCode = 200,
  result = {
    data = [
      {id=7,language="Hindi"},
      {id=8,language="Tamil"}
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I access `language` here?

I have been trying this way

```
print(k.result.data.language)
```

Comment: This is not valid Lua code. You need `{}` instead of `[]`
 for arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt to access the table is almost right, but your table is malformed.

```
k = {
  messageCode = 200,
  result = {
    data = {
      {
        id = 7,
        language = "Hindi"
      },
      {
        id = 8,
        language = "Tamil"
      }
    }
  }
}
print(k.result.data[1].language)
print(k.result.data[2].language)
```

`k.result.data` is an array (numeric lua table), so you have to iterate or access them by number.